# Mongo consecutive writes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency

We're using mongo 4.2, node 14.17.3, mongodb package 3.6.10 - with default read (`local`) and write concern (`w:1`) on a replica set with 3 instances.

Our ecommerce system:

1. uses a transaction to create a sale from the stock (to ensure stock decrease and sale increase are atomic)
2. once this transaction has ended, launches a payement with stripe
3. once this payment is successful, stores the id of this payment with an `updateOne` on the previously created sale.

This works well, but, mostly on heavy loads (but also some other times), the stripe id is missing from the sale, and the `updateOne` returns a `modifiedCount` of 0.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```js
const allocate = async(sale, stocksToAllocate) => {
    const saleJSON = await this.mapping.encode(sale); // transforms sale class instance to json literal
    
    const session = client.startSession();
    try {
        await session.withTransaction(async() => {
            if (sale._id)
                await this.repository.replaceOne({_id: sale._id}, saleJSON, {session});
            else
                await this.repository.insertOne(saleJSON, {session});
    
            for (const stockToAllocate of stocksToAllocate) {
                const stockJSON = await this.stockRepository.findOne({_id: stockToAllocate._id}, {session});
                const stock = await this.stockMapping.decode(stockJSON); // transforms json literal to a stock class instance
                if (stockToAllocate.count < 0) {
                    stock.replenish(-stockToAllocate.count, sale.delivery.shippingAt);
                } else if (stock.canAffect(stockToAllocate.count, sale.delivery.shippingAt)) {
                    stock.affect(stockToAllocate.count, sale.delivery.shippingAt);
                } else {
                    throw new ValidationError('Stock unavailable', {id: stock._id});
                }
    
                const updatedStockJSON = await this.stockMapping.encode(stock);
                await this.stockRepository.replaceOne({_id: stockToAllocate._id}, updatedStockJSON, {session});
            }
        });
    } finally {
        await session.endSession();
    }

    const invoiceItem = {
        customer: sale.getStripeCustomerId(),
        subscription: sale.getStripeSubscriptionId(),
        amount: sale.getPrice().ttc,
        currency: 'EUR',
        description: sale.getName()
    };

    const updatedInvoiceItem = await stripe.invoiceItems.create(invoiceItem);
    await this.repository.updateOne({_id: sale._id}, {$set: {'payment.stripe.chargeId': updatedInvoiceItem.id}}); // this updateOne returns a modifiedCount of 0 sometimes
};
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not related to Mongo.

Before the shared code sample, `this.repository` is wrapped on each request to add the user id to the each db request (something like `this.repository = this.repository.shield(userId)`).

On heavy loads, on the same node instance, a first user may be awaiting the answer from Stripe, while a second user is launching the transaction; thus erasing the `shield`. So when Stripe answers to the first user, the mongo query is enriched with a userId linked to the second user and not the first one.

Fixing this will fix the issue.